# Pass user data extension field from email to website and prefill form field

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, form, email-studio

I am creating an email in email studio. Once a user clicks on my CTA button I want to use their data extension field (username) to pre-fill the login form on my website.

Could I use a link such as this (`example.com/login/?username=%%username%%`) for the button and pass the data through the url and somehow extract that on the login page to pre-fill the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the name as URL-parameter and reading it using javascript for example would be the best option for this. You could do this using the code:

**AMPscript:**

```
%%[
    Var @link
    Set @link = Concat('https://example.com/login?username=', AttributeValue('username'))
]%%
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%">CTA</a>
```

**Javascript on your login-page:**

```javascript
var queryString = window.location.search;
var params = new URLSearchParams(queryString.substring(1)); // drops the leading "?"
var username = parseInt(params.get('username'));
```

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I need. Cheers Markus!

Comment: Great to hear, glad I could help!